# Changing buffers inside of yyparse();

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm attempting to parse a constant string, using predefined grammar, in the middle of parsing another string.

My `main()` calls `yyparse()`, user start typing, and when a certain grammar is matched, such as `MACRO` or something, I wanted to execute `yy_scan_string("...");`
I ran into several problems

- All the constants that I need are created by flex, and I need then in my bison file, which depends on flex output

  - i solved this by copying `#ifndef` statements from the compiled flex portions
- after calling `yy_scan_string` I tried calling `yyparse()` but this threw me into an infinite loop
- if I call `yy_delete_buffer` then I terminate my main parsing, and the code quits.

What am I missing? Seems like a simple task, I just want to parse a stored string, in the middle of parsing a file, and then return to regular parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use `yy_scan_string()` to lex a new string, it would be a good idea to also use the `yypush_buffer_state()` and `yypop_buffer_state()` to save the context of the *current* parsing state. (For a sample implementation, see [Multiple Input Buffers](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html).)

Comment: is there a way not to start a brand new state? as if modify the current stream a little bit?

Comment: by "constants" i meant flex constants, such as `YY_BUFFER_STATE`. I use `%token`s correctly

Comment: It feels like there should be, but that's outside my experience. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to call the bison generated parser while in the middle of another parse? Bear in mind that the parser is stateful -- if you want to use bison in a reentrant manner, you have to specifically request that bison generate a reentrant parser, which is not the default. There is documentation in the bison manual explaining how to request that. See, for example: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Pure-Decl

I'll note, by the way, that flex is also not reentrant by default, and you may have to do similarly there.

Comment: Didn't know about reentrant parsing. Could you provide any more details?